# PySide / PyQt - QWebView - show() multiple pages in sequence?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qwebview

I am looking for QWebView to load and scrape several pages in sequence, but I would like to display the sites along the way.

QWebView.show() seems to open a blank window for all but the final URL.

I assume I have some fundamental misunderstanding of QWebView -- any suggestion on how to accomplish what I want here?

Sample code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
import time

class Web(QApplication):
    did_something = Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(sys.argv)

        self.urls = ["http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.google.com", "http://www.youtube.com"]

        self.w = QWebView()

        self.w.loadFinished.connect(self.loaded)
        self.did_something.connect(self.loadNew)

        self.loadNew()

    def loadNew(self):

        if len(self.urls):
            url = self.urls.pop()
            self.w.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        else:
            self.done()


    def loaded(self):
        print("Loaded URL: {}".format(self.w.url().toString()))
        self.w.show()
        self.doSomething()

    def doSomething(self):
        print("\tDoing something with site!  Printing title: {}".format(self.w.title()))
        time.sleep(2)
        self.did_something.emit()

    def done(self):
        print("\n\nDone")
        self.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    web = Web()
    web.exec_()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to call show() everytime the loaded event occurs? I've changed your example so that after instantiation of the web Object i called web.w.show() once.